# Waiting for Bid vs. Ask

Tags: stocks, investing, shares, bid-ask, spreads

Does a person make a profit when the bid price is higher than what was originally paid for the share? I know that you buy the ask, sell the bid, but if I ask to sell a share at a higher number than what I paid for it, especially if the share is appreciating in value, do I stand a higher chance at making a profit?

Comment: Didn't you ask a **really similar question** yesterday?  https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/134294/confusion-on-bid-vs-ask-and-spread-profits

Comment: "if I ask to sell a share at a higher number than what I paid for it, especially if the share is appreciating in value, do I stand a higher chance at making a profit?"  If you buy an apple for 90 cents, and sell it for 100 cents, then you've made a profit of 10 cents. What's your confusion?

Comment: OP, your confusion may be: you can put in an ASK at ANYTHING YOU WANT. Say a stock is trading around $100.  You can put in an ask at $200 if you like!  No problem! More realistically, you could put in an ask at say $110. Then, just as you say, if more and more people are desperate to buy the stock, it may well fill at $110 !!  So YES that's just what you do!

Comment: I actually _do_ that (what @Fattie proposed), in the after-hours market, and from time to time make some small change with it. So yes, _of course_ you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

> Does a person make a profit when the bid price is higher than what was originally paid for the share?

Only if the person *sells* for that bid price, meaning they place an order and get it executed at that price.

> I ask to sell a share at a higher number than what I paid for it, especially if the share is appreciating in value, do I stand a higher chance at making a profit?

A higher chance than what?  Asking to sell for the same price you paid? Yes, because you have *zero* change of making a profit if you sell for what you paid for it. Note that the higher price you ask, the *smaller* chance you have of getting it filled, so it's a balance between probability of profit and amount of profit.

Note that this probability cannot necessarily be *calculated*, but just conceptually orders sell orders with lower prices get executed first, so the odds that yours gets filled will be lower the higher you put the limit.